# Stream audio from broadcastify api on android

Tags: android, api, audio-streaming, android-networking

I want to make an android app that will stream audio from this http://wiki.radioreference.com/images/5/58/RRaudioAPI_1.2.pdf Documentation API but I  don't know how to go about .i have some experience. I was able to see the data in  I can't figure out how to stream the audio.I dont find any .mp3 files to use as a stream.

Answer (score 0):

Taken in whole from [here](http://programmerguru.com/android-tutorial/android-mediaplayer-example-play-from-internet/).

```
mPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
mPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
try {
    mPlayer.setDataSource(url);
} catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You might not set the URI correctly!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
} catch (SecurityException e) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You might not set the URI correctly!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
} catch (IllegalStateException e) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You might not set the URI correctly!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
try {
    mPlayer.prepare();
} catch (IllegalStateException e) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You might not set the URI correctly!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
} catch (IOException e) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You might not set the URI correctly!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
mPlayer.start();
```

So it looks like all you need to do is create the zendesk URL according to their conventions, and then feed it to a MediaPlayer object.

I highly recommend reading the full tutorial.

Comment: what is the URL i should use?